# vsts phase conditions: How to continue with next phase?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I have a build steps like:
- ...
- npm install
- npm start sb:server (start http-server to serve static files)
- npm run e2e

By the npm start sb:server; it starts the server and it hangs... and doesn't go the next phase which is npm run e2e.

I would like to add a condition to npm run e2e that it should just start without looking previous phase state (failed or succeeded).

I have checked the https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/pipelines/process/conditions?view=vsts#job-status-functions

I can't figure out what kind of command I have to set in 'custom condition' field..

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Every task has a "continue on error" checkbox. Check that. Then, if that task fails, it is treated as a warning, not an error. Execution of subsequent tasks will happen normally.

Comment: Thnx! but the task doesn't fail.. I just get 'Server started...' and it doesn't go to next phase

Comment: @Mar Seems you need to figure out why the task hangs first, as it hangs there and the subsequent tasks will not be started.

Comment: @AndyLi-MSFT That is the reason I am seeking help here..  because it works just fine local on my machine..

Comment: @Mar You need to clarify your question, share the logs for the specific task which hangs.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that the `npm start sb:server` must keeps running so that it can be used all the time. So the command is never finished. The workaround is using cmd task to start another cmd task and run the npm start command in new cmd.