# Azure pipelines: run 'npm start' on a self-hosted VM

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline, npm-start

I want to run a CI/CD pipeline on Azure to build and release a nodejs webapp on a self-hosted machine. I have successfully set up a pipeline to checkout the code, build it and publish the artifacts. Now I want to have a release pipeline that downloads the artifacts created in the build pipeline, deploy it to a deployment group and start the app with `npm start`.

I can manage all the steps except the last one. I have tried adding a custom **"npm start"**  task to the Deployment group job. Azure pipeline gets to that step and then hangs. I guess it just waits for the command to finish, which will not happen, since this is starting the server.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up with what I think it's a better solution: I use [pm2](https://pm2.keymetrics.io) with --watch. Azure DevOps just copies the files to the folder where pm2 is watching.

Answer (score 1):

`npm start` is the equivalent of running whatever value is specified in the scripts( `start` attribute of the package.json file). So you first need to check your package.json file.

There is a speculation in this [case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51302018/vsts-phase-conditions-how-to-continue-with-next-phase) with similar issue:

> the `npm start` must keeps running so that it can be used all the
>   time. So the command is never finished.  The workaround is using cmd
>   task to start another cmd task and run the npm start command in new
>   cmd.

Comment: Indeed, in my case being "react-scripts start". This starts the server which waits for incoming connections.

Comment: It is helpful, but it doesn't get the job done, so unfortunately I cannot accept it.

Comment: Do you try to use cmd task to start another cmd task and run the react-scripts start in new cmd?

Comment: Yes, didn't work for me. Both tasks were killed after 10 seconds. Bu anyway, I found a better approach, see answer.